# How to delimit capacity of edit box?

Tags: c++, winapi, stl

```
    textBoxOutput = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,L"Edit",NULL,WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_VSCROLL | ES_AUTOVSCROLL |  ES_MULTILINE | ES_READONLY ,10,81,500,90,hMainWindow,NULL,NULL,NULL);
.
.
.

    while(!buffer.empty()) //Buffer contains arrays of  wchar_t* type
            {   
                SendMessage(textBoxOutput,EM_SETSEL,GetWindowTextLength(textBoxOutput),GetWindowTextLength(textBoxOutput));
                SendMessage(textBoxOutput,EM_REPLACESEL,FALSE, (LPARAM) buffer.front()); 

                delete [] buffer.front();
                buffer.pop();
            }
```

There are maximally 30000 wide characters visible. Is it possible to at least increase this number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`EM_LIMITTEXT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761607%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message for this. From the reference:

> It sets the text limit of an edit control. The text limit is the
>   maximum amount of text, in TCHARs, that the user can type into the
>   edit control.